# ASP.Net Linq to SQL Dependent (Cascading) Properties (Type / SubType)

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

I've been getting started with Dynamic Data Websites in ASP.Net recently using Linq to SQL as my entity source.  To give you an idea of my progress here's what I've already done:

Scaffold settings at the entity and property levels (using ScaffoldTable, MetadataType and ScaffoldColumn attributes:

```
[ScaffoldTable(true)]
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductCategoryMetadata))]
public partial class ProductCategory
{
}

public class ProductCategoryMetadata
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public EntitySet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public EntitySet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
}
```

I've also learned the approach for applying business rules like custom update stored prods and setting tracking columns like UpdateDate/UpdateBy in the UpdateEntity(Entity instance) methods.

Something I haven't figured out yet is how (and if possible) to do cascading parameters like a Type/SubType relationship.  Here's what my partial entity model looks like:

**Product**
ProductGuid,
ProductTypeGuid,
ProductSubTypeGuid,
ProductName

**ProductType**
ProductTypeGuid,
ProductTypeName

**ProductSubType**
ProductSubTypeGuid,
ProductTypeGuid,
ProductTypeName

ProductSubType is nullable, hence the foreign key schema.  Can anyone comment on the possibility of getting the Edit modes for Product to filter allowable ProductSubTypes based on the ProductType selection within the Dynamic Entity templating?  Or would I have to go completely custom to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Word of warning: once you get outside of simple CRUD based on a basic set of related tables, Dynamic Data sites can get very hacky and become maintenance nightmares.  I've fallen prey to the simplicity of DD sites, and have paid the price.

Comment: That's exactly my concern, Garrison.  I've adopted the model of if it gets too cloodgy I'm creating custom pages.  If it stays simple I'm using the the DD templated pages, and if not I'm pulling that entity out of the scaffold and building from ground up...